# what is the surplus-control of generation?

Tags: frequency, generator, frequency-response, power-grid, systemresponse

Reading the ''P1 – Policy 1: Load-Frequency Control and Performance'' document, published by UCTE in 2009 (it is available on internet for all) I noted that there are many contributions to Load-Frequency control from the electric power system. In particular, in addition to the Network Power-Frequency Characteristic of Primary control (provided by generators) and to the self-regulating effect of loads, there is a surplus control of generation to primary frequency deviations.
In the document it is stated:
''The SURPLUS-CONTROL OF GENERATION is an experienced linear response of approximately 50 % of all generation units reacting to FREQUENCY DEVIATIONS. This results in an additional value
of self-control of generation, that is calculated based on the mean generation power in the system. This SURPLUS CONTROL OF GENERATION exists in addition to the MINIMUM NETWORK POWER
CHARACTERISTIC OF PRIMARY CONTROL.''

But where does this contribution come from? Is it related to kinetic energy of generators?

Comment: It reads as if it's power stations monitoring the frequency and responding to fluctuations automatically by increasing or decreasing output to somewhat compensate for deviations independent of central control. The proportion of units responding  (50%) is presumably kept well below 100% partly because some simply cannot respond but also to allow central control to be layered over the top without risking over 100% compensation, and so risk oscillations....

Comment: ... At this level would introduce damping and the different grid locations, response times, etc, of the units would reduce the chance of operator-induced oscillation modes. This is just how I read the doc, though, I am no expert on this area. The English is very bad though: more likely because it was written by lawyers than because it was written by non-native speakers. https://eepublicdownloads.entsoe.eu/clean-documents/pre2015/publications/entsoe/Operation_Handbook/Policy_1_final.pdf

Comment: I think you are talking about generators on AGC (automatic generation control).  See [here](https://www.nerc.com/comm/RSTC_Reliability_Guidelines/Integrating_Reporting_ACE_with_NERC_Reliability_Standards.pdf).